# plotting all solutions of differential equations for many parameters

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list whose elements is in the form `{{f[x]-> some function of x}}`. How do I manipulate it to  bring in the form `{f1(x), f2(x) ... }`. The list is generated by `DSolve` inside table.

```
Table[DSolve[{de, y[0] == k}, y[x], x], {k , -2, 2}]
```

The output is in the form

```
 {{{y[x] -> -2 E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] -> -E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] ->  0}}, {{y[x] -> E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] -> 2 E^-x^2}}}
```

I need to plot all these solutions.

I need it in the form

```
{-2 E^-x^2, -E^-x^2,  0, E^-x^2,2 E^-x^2}
```

I tried something like

```
f[x] /. #[[1]] & /@ Table[DSolve[{de, y[0] == k}, y[x], x], {k , -2, 2}]
```

But no luck :(

Comment: `Flatten[yourList][[All,2]]` if you need only function bodies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

```
sol = {{{y[x] -> -2 E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] -> -E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] -> 0}}, {{y[x] -> 
      E^-x^2}}, {{y[x] -> 2 E^-x^2}}};

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol // Flatten], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just a variant: function of parameter and extract solution at start and the use of `ParametricNDSolve` (though not needed for this particular example but just to show an alternative):

```
fun[k_] := [x] /. DSolve[{f'[x] == -2 x f[x], f[0] == k}, {f[x]}, x][[1]]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[fun[j], {j, -2, 2}], {x, 0, 1},PlotLegends ->"Expressions"]
```

or

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -2 x y[x], y[0] == p}, {y}, {x, 0, 1},{p}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[j][x] /. sol, {j, -2, 2}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]